# elastic beanstalk can't find the include file

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to PHP and ealstic beanstalk , the code works on my mac. On AWS E BS on getting error file not found.
The code is

```
require_once '/var/app/current/PhpProject1/include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
```

the error is:

```
require_once(/var/app/current/PhpProject1/include/DB_Functions.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/PhpProject1/login.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this hard coded?

`require_once '/var/app/current/PhpProject1/include/DB_Functions.php';`

If so, I very much doubt that your site on Amazon will be in the exact same folder.

You should have a `SITE_ROOT` constant or similar, defined probably in your `public/index.php`, or in some config bootstrap file.

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__)); 
if (!defined('SITE_ROOT'))
{
    define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));
}
```

Then you can require as follows:

`require_once SITE_ROOT.'/include/DB_Functions.php';`

That *should* work on both servers!

Comment: Sorry the latest error is  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/app/current/include/DB_Functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php7') in /var/app/current/PhpProject1/login.php on line 18

Comment: `cd` into the folder where the file is, then type `pwd` to get the actual path. Again though, this will not be the same path on your remote, you need to set the `SITE_ROOT` folder as a constant